# Mocha Unit Test on Swagger failing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, swagger

I am very new to node js. I have written a swagger API and now I am writing a test case for it using mocha libraries. Below is my piece of test.js and I am getting error.

```
var assert = require("assert");
var should = require('chai').should();
var testAssistants = require("swagger-test");

describe('Test API', function () {
    var invokeAPI;
    before(function (done) {
        testAssistants.parse('../api/swagger.yaml',
            function (authInvoker, error) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("Cannot proceed: Swagger file is invalid");
                    error.every(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                    process.exit();
                } else {
                    invokeAPI = authInvoker;
                }
                done();
            });
    });

    describe('http://localhost:8080/v1/id/123/test', function () {
        it('should give results', function (done) {
            this.timeout(10000);
            var result = invokeAPI("GET", "/v1/id/123/test", {});
            let resJson = result._getJSON();
            testAssistants.assertSwaggerResult(result, 200);
            result.response.body.length.should.be.greaterThan(0);
            should.equal(resJson.length, 2);
            done();
        });
    });
})
```

I am running the test class using `node_modules/.bin/mocha` and getting below error:

```
"before all" hook in "Test API":
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (D:\test-node-api\test\test.js)
```

What is that I am missing ?

Comment: For `before`, maybe `done()` is in the wrong line. Check it. Maybe its right place is outside the block.

Comment: The error means that `done` isn't getting called in `before` within the 2 second timeout.  Is your callback for `testAssistants.parse` getting called?

Comment: I think the testAssistants.parse is not getting called at all. Because I tried giving invalid path of swagger.yaml but the error did not change. I thought it would go in the (error) block.